# Is there a way to detect a FocusOut event on 2 widgets in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

What I want is to be free to choose the date as long as I am on the dateEntry widget (even if i click on down arrow this one won't be detroyed) and destroy this last (dateEntry) if I click some where else.

The problem is tkcalender is made by multiple widgets that's why the focusOut event is set just on one of them.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

def ok(e):
    print(cal.get_date())


root = Tk()
cal = DateEntry(root, year=2010)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
cal.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: cal.destroy())
cal.bind('<Return>', ok)  # validate with Enter
cal.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

If you run the code then you click on the arrow of the DateEntry this one is destroyed and I want this one to stay there until you click some where else in the window to be destroyed.

Comment: Do you mean you want the popup with dates stay until you pick a date, and does not destroy itself when it loses focus?

Comment: i want it to be destroyed just when you click some where else , if you run the code bellow and click on the arrow this one will be destroyed. sorry for my english i know im bad @HenryYik

Comment: you can see [source code of DateEntry](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/tkcalendar/dateentry.html#DateEntry). If you bind to `cal._top_cal.bind()` then arrow shows calendar but it destroys when you click in date in Entry so it is still not good soluton.

Comment: no that did not help @furas

Comment: @HenryYik your solution helped me a lot thanx plz if you can post here again i will colse this

Comment: @ALIBENALI sure, glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the `DateEntry` not to be destroyed when you click open the calendar. That is doable by checking your current focus and `pass` if the current focus is a `Calendar` object.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry, Calendar

def check_focus(event):
    current = root.focus_get()
    if not isinstance(current,Calendar):
        cal.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

cal = DateEntry(root, year=2010)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
cal.bind('<FocusOut>', check_focus)
tk.Button(root,text="Click").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Try pressing tab to change focus and see.